# Build errors after updating to Angular 9 and Typescript 3.8.3

Tags: angular, typescript

After updating my WebAPI project to Angular 9 and Typescript 3.8.3, I get errors upon building my application:
[image]

Then I tried executing some commands, deleting node_modules and executing npm install, I tried updating my dependencies so I ended up with Angular preview version (10).

I still have those errors and I'm not sure what should I do next to fix this.

Here is tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

What could be causing this issue?

**EDIT**
I downgraded Angular to version 9, then deleted node_modules and executed npm i command and I still have errors.
This is my package.json now

```
{
  "name": "score-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.0.2",
    "angular-md2": "^6.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "compressible": "^2.0.18",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^4.0.2",
    "ngx-tempusdominus-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tempusdominus-bootstrap-4": "^5.1.2",
    "tempusdominus-core": "^5.0.3",
    "tslib": "^1.11.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.38",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

It seems I get the same errors still:
[image]

Comment: Your package.json specifies angular 10, and the question talks about angular 9 ? How did you upgrade ? Did you follow [angular update guide](https://update.angular.io/) ?

Comment: Yes, I followed that guide when upgrading from 8 to 9. Then, after I encountered errors, I executed some commands to update typescript, update other dependencies and I probably updated Angular to version 10 as well.

Comment: You shouldn't use angular 10 yet. It is not ready for production use

Comment: Okay, but these errors started happening on Angular 9.

Comment: Roll back to angular 9, and then start debugging. I've upgraded 2 projects from 5 to 9. When I had errors, that was because node_modules had old dependencies. Delete it and the running `npm i` fixed odd errors. Don't update typescript youself, only run ng-cli update commands, and then come back with your new errors and your updated package.json if you still have errors. Then we could help.

Comment: Okay, I did that, but unfortunately, the errors still persist, I updated the post with my new package.json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this. The problem was that the visual studio was using the wrong version of typescript.

Simply installing [this version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.typescript-383) for visual studio fixed it.